# Kendo Grid: Use of attributes in Kendo:column

Tags: jsp, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to find the correct syntax to apply class for kendo-column using attributes.
I have tried the below code but this syntax does not support current kendo version.

```
<kendo:grid-column attributes=" class=table-cell"></kendo:grid-column>
```

What is the correct syntax for using attributes in kendo:grid-column? 
I am using kendo-taglib-2018.3.1017 library.

It gives the following error

> Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined.

Also my grid-column tag is inside jstl loop to have generic grid.

Comment: Based on [this property](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.attributes), the attributes atr set as an object. Did you tried something like `<kendo:grid-column attributes="{'class':'table-cell'}">` ?

Comment: yes, but it does not work..

Answer (score 0):

The [online documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/jsp/grid/column) is not very explanatory and appears to have some weirdness with a newline in the parenthesis.

> attributes [java.lang.Object]
>   HTML attributes of the table cell (
>   ) rendered for the column.
>
> Example
>
> ```
> <kendo:grid-column attributes="attributes">
> </kendo:grid-column>
> ```

Do you get better results with

```
<kendo:grid-column attributes="class='table-cell'"></kendo:grid-column>
```